# How do I separate the text from my ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I make the captions not overlap?

```
mayors <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/umbertomig/intro-prob-stat-FGV/master/datasets/brmayors.csv")
ggplot(mayors, aes(DESCRICAO_GRAU_INSTRUCAO)) + geom_bar()
'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rotate the labels (here to 45, but you can pick) with `theme`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mayors, aes(DESCRICAO_GRAU_INSTRUCAO)) + geom_bar() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]